# Python 3.x array, new array using rank logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Assume a sorted list that has values from -20 to 20:

```
[20,19,19,17,14,12,12,12,10,1,1,1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-7,-9,-15,-16]
```

I need to create a new list that computes the rank of each item in the context of whether it's positive or negative. In other words, there will be two rank ranges (one for the positive items, one for the negative items). The extent of the rank depends on how many items in the array are positive/negative. I want to use inverse rank logic; the higher the value, the lower the rank.

Using the above example, `20` would be in last place since it's the largest. More precisely "last place" would be 12th place (since there are 12 items in the list that are positive). And by the same logic, `1` would be first place (I guess it's not life or death as to which `1` we choose). Likewise `-16` should be last place (9th place) for the negative side (there are 9 negative items). For clarity I want to distinguish the negative ranks from the positive using a negative sign. so `-16` would become `-9` and `-15` would become `-8` and `-9` would become `-7`, ect.

Expected output:

```
[12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9]
```

### Question

How do I construct a new list with the rank logic as detailed above using native python?

- **Note:** the number ratio of positive items / negative items in the list could change. In this case it's 12 positive items & 9 negative items, but I would need an approach that is robust for the general case. Just as an example, 18 positive & 3 negative, or 3 positive & 18 negative.

Comment: please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Comment: maybe tgo show exemple of expected output(expected new list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets it done:

```
a = [20,19,19,17,14,12,12,12,10,1,1,1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-7,-9,-15,-16]

positive = sum(1 for i in a if i >= 0)
negative = sum(1 for i in a if i < 0) + 1

result = list(range(positive, 0, -1)) + list(range(-1, -negative, -1))

result
#[12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not really clear. However, what about:

```
def do_it(list_):
   posit, negat = [x for x in list_ if x >= 0], [x for x in list_ if x < 0]
   posit.sort()
   pos_rank = [(pos + 1, elem) for pos, elem in enumerate(posit)]
   neg_rank = [(-1 * (pos + 1), elem) for pos, elem in enumerate(negat)]
   return pos_rank + neg_rank


l = [20,19,19,17,14,12,12,12,10,1,1,1,-1,-2,-2,-2,-2,-7,-9,-15,-16]
print(do_it(l))
# [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 10), (5, 12), (6, 12), (7, 12), (8, 14), (9, 17), (10, 19), (11, 19), (12, 20), (-1, -1), (-2, -2), (-3, -2), (-4, -2), (-5, -2), (-6, -7), (-7, -9), (-8, -15), (-9, -16)]
```